# Minimize outlook to tray

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003, notification-area

I am using MS 2003. I want my Outlook to be minimized to tray.

I know the process that right click on outlook icon in tray. But I cannot see outlook icon in system tray.

What can be wrong? Can anybody explain?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that Outlook is still running?

Comment: @Nathaniel My Outlook is running. As when I open it, it will show me new mails if there are any

Comment: then perhaps its hidden? Does this always happen? Have you tried restarting the program? I have had times when explorer crashes, some of the icons don't reappear, even though they are running.

Comment: @Nathaniel Restart means? I several time close and open this program. Each time if I got a new mail then it is shown in inbox. But when the program is running, it is not shown in system tray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I am now using Outlook Express and using 3rd party software I succeeded to get my outlook to be minimized in system tray.

Comment: what 3rd party software? which Outlook Express version? A bit more info goes a long way.

Answer (score 0):

Please tell us what operating system you are running. Presume you mean you are using Microsoft Outlook 2003 as well, it's not clear from the question.

It might be that your system tray icons are being hidden, depending on which version of Windows you are using there are different ways to show these again.

Comment: I am using Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on taskbar and select Properties. In the Notification area click on the Customize button and look for Microsoft Office Outlook. In the Behavior drop down list select Always show.

[image]

Comment: But even this is also not shown in current items. I had checked it.

Comment: Do you mean that Outlook isn't in that list?

Comment: @Nathaniel Yes, exactly, Outlook is not there in that list.

Comment: Then perhaps try reinstalling outlook, only thing I can think of.